# Не работает переход по URL вида 'page-'

Tags: php, pdo, router

Здравствуйте! Не работает  `URL` для перехода по страницам. Сама пагинация рабочая, но почему-то `URL` вида `"page-"` не воспринимается базой данных. Она почему-то подставляет его в запрос.

Вот ошибка, которая появляется:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on
>   boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\models\Product.php:56 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\CatalogController.php(29):
>   Product::getProductsListByCategory('13', 0) #1
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\components\Router.php(68):
>   CatalogController->actionCategory('13', 'page2') #2
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(18): Router->run() #3 {main} thrown in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\models\Product.php on line 56

**Сам URL:**

```
category/([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)' => 'catalog/category/$1/$2
```

**Product.php где выдает ошибку**

```
  public static function getProductsListByCategory($categoryId = false, $page = 1)
{
    if ($categoryId) {

        $page = intval($page);            
        $offset = ($page - 1) * self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT;

        $db = Db::getConnection();            
        $products = array();
        $result = $db->query("SELECT id, name, price, is_new FROM product "
                . "WHERE status = '1' AND category_id = '$categoryId' "
                . "ORDER BY id ASC "                
                . "LIMIT ".self::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT
                . ' OFFSET '. $offset);

        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
            $products[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $products[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
            //$products[$i]['image'] = $row['image'];
            $products[$i]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $products[$i]['is_new'] = $row['is_new'];
            $i++;
        }

        return $products;       
    }
}
```

**actionCategory в CatalogController.php**

```
public function actionCategory($categoryId, $page = 1)
{
    $categories = array();
    $categories = Category::getCategoriesList();

    $categoryProducts = array();
    $categoryProducts = Product::getProductsListByCategory($categoryId, $page);

    $total = Product::getTotalProductsInCategory($categoryId);

    $pagination = new Pagination($total, $page, Product::SHOW_BY_DEFAULT, 'page-');

    require_once(ROOT . '/views/catalog/category.php');

    return true;
}
```

Comment: фреймворк Yii2?

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Нет. Чистый PHP.

Comment: @kittycat_13 у вас же написано что в $result не объект, а `bool` как вы эту переменную получили?

Comment: Вот код всего метода, где происходить обрщение к БД:

Comment: Добавила в пост.

Comment: Зато, когда прописываю в ручную в URL http://localhost/category/13/2, спокойно переходит на вторую страницу.

Comment: @kittycat_13 что у вас за ORM для работы с бд? Она в месте `$result = $db->query` вернула `true` или `false`, добавьте проверку на то что в `$result` и посмотрите в каком случае там boolean значение, что-то с ORM не так

Comment: Использую только PDO, что в самом PHP

Comment: Нашла проблему почему выдает FALSE. Оказывается, при переходе на страницу, отличную от 1, в переменную $page не записывается, ровным счетом, ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Напишите

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```